# Не работает обработчик ошибок try catch

Tags: php

Почему блок catch не срабатывает, если будет ошибка? Если биндить несуществующие переменные.

```
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO bookmark(`user_id`, `question_id`) VALUES(:userId, :questionId)";
    $bookmark = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $bookmark->bindValue(':userId', trim($u), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $bookmark->bindValue(':questionId', trim($qq), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $bookmark->execute();

}

catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Ошибка';
    die();
}

echo 'Добавлено';
```

Comment: все у вас срабатывает, исключение просто не выбрасывает никто. Переменные не существовали, пока вы их не использовали. Скормили запросу `null`-значения, которые по всей видимости успешно вставились в таблицу. Измените таблицу на `not null` столбцы и повесьте уникальный индекс (или первичный ключ) на столбцы и получите ваше исключение